# Fody Exception in Release Mode Symbol file .dll.mdb does not match assembly .dll

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, fody, fody-propertychanged

I'm having a problems building a PCL in Xamarin Studio on the Mac. It works fine in debug mode but fody throws an exception in Release Mode.

Exception during build is listed below.

```
Error: Fody: An unhandled exception occurred:
Exception:
Symbol file `XXX/obj/Release/XXX.dll.mdb' does not match assembly `XXX/obj/Release/XXX.dll'
StackTrace:
at Mono.CompilerServices.SymbolWriter.MonoSymbolFile.CheckGuidMatch (Guid other, System.String filename, System.String assembly) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.CompilerServices.SymbolWriter.MonoSymbolFile..ctor (System.String filename, Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition module) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.CompilerServices.SymbolWriter.MonoSymbolFile.ReadSymbolFile (Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition module, System.String filename) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Cecil.Mdb.MdbReaderProvider.GetSymbolReader (Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition module, System.String fileName) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Cecil.ModuleReader.ReadSymbols (Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition module, Mono.Cecil.ReaderParameters parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Cecil.ModuleReader.CreateModuleFrom (Mono.Cecil.PE.Image image, Mono.Cecil.ReaderParameters parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.ReadModule (System.IO.Stream stream, Mono.Cecil.ReaderParameters parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.ReadModule (System.String fileName, Mono.Cecil.ReaderParameters parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at InnerWeaver.ReadModule () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at InnerWeaver.Execute () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
Source:
Mono.Cecil.Mdb
TargetSite:
Void CheckGuidMatch(System.Guid, System.String, System.String)
```

Comment: are the timestamps on the mdb and the dll the same?

Comment: did u ever solve this?

Comment: Please mark @matthewrdev has the correct solution for this issue.

Answer (score 16):

Fody needs the debug information (*.mdb file) associated with the outputted assembly to perform the weaving step. Release builds by default turn off the **Debug Information** field within **Build** -> **Compiler** in a projects settings.

Having this build option set to `None` disables debug symbolication and results in the mdb file getting out of sync, hence the `Symbol file 'XXX/obj/Release/XXX.dll.mdb' does not match assembly XXX/obj/Release/XXX.dll` exception.

Therefore you need to enable **Symbols Only** or **Full** when you build projects in release mode when Fody is integrated into the build process:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You may have already, but I'd start with this if it was me:

- Right click on your solution
- Properties
- Configuration Properties / Configuration

In the "Configuration" drop down in the top left, check that the "Debug" configuration (re: Platform | Build | Deploy) matches "Release".